# Android list of choices or custom text

Tags: android, listview, widget

I'm looking for an Android widget that provides the following functionality: I want to get text from the user, and the user can either select from a list of choices or enter their own text.

I'm having a hard time coming up with the right keywords for google. Custom ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the "list of choices" to fold down from the text entry area, then `AutoCompleteTextView` is the widget that you want.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/AutoComplete) demonstrating its use. You basically hand it an `Adapter` for the stuff to go in the list via `setAdapter()`, and use the `android:completionThreshold` attribute to indicate how many characters the user must type in before Android will attempt to find matches and display them.

Answer (score 0):

You look for AutoCompleteTextView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html